# How do I calculate the number of months between two dates in a specific year

Tags: excel-formula

I have an potentially random set of start dates and term lengths in a Excel/Google Sheets.

```
Example - considering 2019 as the year in question
January 2017, 24 months
January 2019, 12 months
April 2019, 12 months
May 2020, 7 months
```

I need to calculate the number of months out of each term in a specific year.

```
Example answers - number of months in given timeframe that are in 2019
February 2017, 24 months A: 1 months
January 2019, 12 months A: 12 months
April 2019, 12 months A: 9 months
May 2020, 7 months A: 0 months
```

Calculating start and end dates with `DATEDIFF` is easy. Without an extreme amount of convoluted logic I haven't been able to pick out how many months fall in a given year.

Am I missing something beyond a series of nested conditionals to determine if the start month is in the specified year?

Getting conditional statements that are too deeply nested is not ideal because there are additional layers that need to be added, such as if the term will be renewed, etc. that add additional complications.

Comment: Can you explain the logic used to derive the answer? Not following

Comment: " an extreme amount of convoluted logic" -> you can share this version to clarify what you'd tried + where are you going (with the logic).

Comment: Please edit your question and provide more detail about the logic. It's totally unclear what you want to achieve.

Comment: Sure am glad other people don't follow. This question is phrased like it's a no brainier easy solution, but I can't find the pattern between the date given, terms given, and solution.

Comment: The given year is 2019

Comment: Are the start date and the length of term in separate columns or all in one cell?

Comment: Are the start dates actual dates? or are they strings?

Comment: @urdearboy does my answer below clear any of the confusion?  I kept getting confused about the specific year because it was never supplied as part of the question.

Comment: Thanks for the response @ForwardEd. For posterity - the year may change. Dates are not strings, though I see what you did in your example to account for that. Your solution worked well as the foundation for my final solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Assumptions

Your start date and months are both strings in separate columns.
You can convert them to actual dates in a helper column.
Data is layed out per image below.

## General

I am just laying out my solution in a simplified method.   You can in turn nest formulas, hard code items, etc to suit your needs

## Process

Convert your start date from a string in A6 to an actual excel date and place it in D6.  I simply used the following formula, but other methods exist and may be needed depending on system settings.

```
=DATEVALUE(A6)
```

Calculate the end date based on month offset and place it in E6.  To achieve this I used the following formula which is different then DATEDIFF which you seem to understand.

```
=EOMONTH(D6,LEFT(B6,FIND(" ",B6)-1)-2)+1
```

Place the given year you are looking for in a designated cell.  In this case I chose F1.

Based on the integer that is placed in F1 generate an actual date for the first month of the year and for the last month of the year.  I placed these in F2 and F3 respectively.

```
=DATE(F1,1,1)

=DATE(F1,12,1)

Note:  These can easily be embedded in formulas but can be cleaner and make formulas easier to read.
```

Next you have 6 conditions to test for:

1. The entire period is before the given year => 0
2. The entire period is after the given year => 0
3. The period starts before the given year and finishes after the end of the given year => 12
4. The period starts before the given year and finishes within the given year => formula 1
5. The period starts within the given year and finishes after the given year => formula 2
6. The period starts within the given year and finishes within the given year = formula 3

I am going to approach this with a nested IF and will explain it in steps.  Condition 1 and 2 both result in 0.  Therefore check if either condition is true and return 0 if so:

```
=IF(OR(E6<$F$2,D6>$F$3),0,
```

Note the formula is not finished.  The false part of the if was not supplied and its where we can check condition 3.

```
=IF(OR(E6<$F$2,D6>$F$3),0,IF(AND(D6<=$F$2,E6>=$F$3),12,
```

So this checks if the Start and end date span the current year.  Note I use <= and >= because if the period start date is equal to the start of the current year and  or the end date is equal to the end of the current year its the same result and saves going through a math calculation later.  Again the false side has not been provided.  To fill this part in, you need to check condition 4.

Check to see if the period start date is before the given year.  You do not need to check the end date at the same time because if the end date is after you know it was already caught by your previous condition 3 check.  If it is, the month of the end date will tell you how many months were in the given year.  The month of the end of the period calculation is formula 1

```
=IF(OR(E6<$F$2,D6>$F$3),0,IF(AND(D6<=$F$2,E6>=$F$3),12,IF(D6<=$F$2,MONTH(E6),
```

Now you now the next condition check already knows you period start date is after the start of the year otherwise it would have already been caught by one of the previous checks.  what you need is to determine if then end of the period is to the end of the year, and calculate the number of month from start of period to end of year which is formula 2.

```
=IF(OR(E6<$F$2,D6>$F$3),0,IF(AND(D6<=$F$2,E6>=$F$3),12,IF(D6<=$F$2,MONTH(E6),IF(E6>=$F$3,12-MONTH(D6)+1,
```

There are no further conditions to check as you have caught all the possibilities except one, the final condition.  All that needs to be determined is is formula 3 and close all the brackets for your nested IFs.

```
=IF(OR(E6<$F$2,D6>$F$3),0,IF(AND(D6<=$F$2,E6>=$F$3),12,IF(D6<=$F$2,MONTH(E6),IF(E6>=$F$3,12-MONTH(D6)+1,MONTH(E6)-MONTH(D6)+1))))
```

Place the formula above in G6 and copy down as required.

This process is not the only way just the first one I went to.  Others may have a more elegant solution.

[image: POC]

Answer (score 0):

That suggestion worked well. Below is what I did with a few additional modifications.

Whether the term was automatically renewed, or whether it was expected to end had to be added. However with your suggestions that was a simple modification.

Reference the image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovvob.jpg)

The year under scrutiny is in R2 - in this case 2019
Start date - column H
Term length - column I
Renewal status - column K (if set to yes the term is assumed to continue indefinitely)
End Date - column P
Months from the given term that occur during the year in question in column Q

Q2 stores the year under scrutiny
The row used in the example is 208 (sorry)

formula in column P checks to see if the renewal is set to Y or N. If N uses the term end indicated. If Y sets the term end to 12/31 of the year in question.

```
=IF(K208="N",EOMONTH(H208,I208-1),DATE($Q$2,12,31))
```

Note one slight change to indicate the end date as the end of the month since what I care about is full months, not down to the date.

Examples
A term starting 2/2019 for one month would last from 2/1/2019 through 2/28/2019 (not 2/1/2019 through 3/1/2019)
A term starting 2/2019 for three months would last from 2/1/2019 through 4/30/2019 (not 2/1/2019 through 5/1/2019)

I then essentially used the formula from Forward Ed for to calculate the number of months I cared about based on the logic he described.

```
=IF(OR(P208<DATE($Q$2,1,1),H208>DATE($Q$2,12,31)),0,IF(AND(H208<=DATE($Q$2,1,1),P208>=DATE($Q$2,12,31)),12,IF(H208<=DATE($Q$2,1,1),MONTH(P208),IF(P208>=DATE($Q$2,12,31),12-MONTH(H208)+1,MONTH(P208)-MONTH(H208)+1))))
```